# Show all tabs and trailing spaces in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, ide, text-editor

I have to use Visual Studio 2022 for my job. For my personal project I program in vim. I have my vim configured to show `»` for **all tabs** and `·` for **only trailing spaces** (only at the end of line).

Is there a way to reproduce this behavior in VS?
If not, what's the closest I can get?
I know there's an option in *Edit > Advanced > View White Space*, but turning that option on shows all the space characters all the time.

I'm interested in Visual Studio, not VS Code.